# PHP problema na codificação, erro de caracteres em arquivo PDF

Tags: php, html

Bom estou com um problema que pelo visto não é muito incomum, Já vi algumas perguntas semelhantes e nenhuma das repostas me ajudou.

Estou com um formulário *HTML* onde as informações nele inseridas estão sendo capturadas via *POST* pelo *PHP*, até ai tudo certo. Para salvar esses dados como *PDF* estou utilizando a biblioteca **mPDF 6.0**. Basicamente estou usando uma página *HTML* como modelo pro *PDF* e as informações pegas pelo *PHP* são substituídas no modelo.

O erro é que os dados que foram pegos pelo *PHP* não podem ter acentos ou "ç" já que aparecem de forma estranha, mas isso não acontece com o *HTML*, logo tenho uma parte do *PDF* com acentuação correta que a página de modelo em *HTML* e o que vem do *PHP* não aceita acentuação.

Exemplo do que ocorre:

[image: Nome do PDF caso tenha acento]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Perceba que possui acento no HTML sem problemas e na parte PHP acontece o erro.

Algumas coisas que já tentei:

Colocar o Header no PHP: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8')`

Nos arquivos HTML a meta utf8: `meta charset="utf-8"`

Salvar os arquivos em *UTF-8*, todos já estão assim.

E por último tentei essa conversão que não faz muito sentido mas foi uma sugestão que vi em algumas respostas: `$pdf = mb_convert_encoding($pdf, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');`

Sem sucesso o problema continua mesmo estando tudo em UTF-8.

Códigos:

Fomulário

```
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="pdf/index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkFile();">

        Número de Protocolo:<input type="text" name="f_protocolo" id="protocol"> Marca para Registro:<input type="text" name="f_registro">

    </form>
</body>
```

Modelo:

```
    <div>

        <p>Número de protocolo: #f_protocolo</p>


        <p>Marca para registro: #f_registro</p>

    </div>
</fieldset>
```

PHP:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se alguém tiver ideia do que pode estar acontecendo, aceito sugestões.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Tente usar `$mpdf->WriteHTML(utf8_decode($pdf));` e retire o mb_convert_enconding.

Comment: Tentei utilizar e agora quando tento enviar o formulário aparece "HTML contains invalid UTF-8 character(s)" consegui arrumar isso com outra linha de código mas o erro de acentos ainda persiste, mas valeu a tentativa.

Comment: No seu template modelo voce define o charset no header? Se não, tente fazer isso.

Comment: O modelo eu coloquei  "<meta charset="UTF-8">" já que é HTML.

Comment: Entao tente retirar o header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8') . Pode acontecer de duplicar o charset e ficar todo estranho mesmo. mPDF é um biblioteca chata de mexer hehehe. Ou tente fazer $mpdf->WriteHTML(utf8_encode($pdf));

Comment: Estou começando a achar bem chata mesmo, o problema continua, se eu não conseguir logo vou procurar outro método para gerar PDF talvez seja a biblioteca.

Comment: Se tá tudo UTF-8 tenta remover as conversões `utf8_encode`.

Comment: Nada ainda, acho que o problema não seja no PHP, talvez seja o mPDF mesmo. De qualquer forma agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Por favor, não use imagens do seu código na pergunta, assim dificulta muito o pessoal que quer te ajudar, copie e cole o código, se não souber edentar, deixa que alguém edenta para você ...

Comment: Agradeço o aviso, mas agora eu já sei disso, essa foi uma das primeiras perguntas que eu fiz aqui no SO, não cometo mais esse erro.  =/